Babinet's principle, Arago point and Airy's disc
As far as I'm concerned, Arago's point is the central pattern we observe when we illuminate an opaque disc-like object, while an Airy disc is the pattern we obtain when passing light through a disc-like hole in an opaque mask. Nonetheless, since Babinet's principle states that "an opening and an opaque mask with the same geomtrical form and identical illumination produce identical diffraction patterns", shouldn't Arago's point and Airy's disc be the exact same thing?

Not really. Arago's point develops as a result of diffraction at a finite distance from the diffracting object, here the opaque disc. Airy's pattern is what antenna designer's call the (Fraunhofer) radiation pattern and it is in the infinity but can be focused by a lens to a finite distance and projected to a screen.
